# Find class in model with has many relation

Tags: grails, convention-over-configur

I have following Model:

```
TestProfessional { 
    static hasMany = [answers: Answer]
}
Answer { 
String answer;
}
```

How to find TestProfessional with answers having specified id?

Comment: Did you want to retrieve all answer related to particular test?

Comment: You are calling finder on wrong domain.

Comment: rather all tests with answers i have.

Comment: Where is your TestProfessional domain?

Comment: it's Test class, i've made changes to question.

Answer (score 0):

That worked:

```
def questions = TestProfessional.withCriteria(uniqueResult: false) {
            answers {
            inList("id", answersIds)
        }}
```